# How to draw an ellipse?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

As I know, I can draw a circle using:

```
\draw (1,0) circle (2)
```

I try this kind of method to draw a `\draw` ellipse, failed. Would you tell me how to draw a ellipse? What's wrong with the code below?

The code is:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}

% Define the rings. Store them in macros to make things
% more flexible.
 \def\boundellipse {(0,0) ellipse (10,5)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Then we draw the rings
\draw \boundellipse;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PSTricks' ellipse syntax might be closer to your requirement. Here it is `\psellipse(<centerX, centerY>)(<semi-major-length, semi-minor-length>)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](8,6)
    \psellipse[linecolor=red](4,3)(4,3)
    \pscircle[linecolor=blue](4,3){2}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 186):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz \draw (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);


or

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\myellipse{(0,0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm)}


\begin{document}
\tikz \draw \myellipse ;


or

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw \myellipse;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it did work. Thanks, however if I draw a circle like this way:  \def\boundellipse {(0,0) circle(2)} then draw , it can work, why can not ellipse?

Comment: Is there any way to assign a name to an ellipse drawn this way? I need to store the ellipse in a "variable" (name) and use the name to later align other elements...

Answer (score 31):

The pgfmanual gives `\draw (a,b) circle [x radius=1cm, y radius=2cm];`

With a macro

```
\newcommand{\boundellipse}[3]% center, x rad, y rad
{(#1) ellipse [x radius=#2,y radius=#3]
}
```

Comment: +1. A pgfmanual extract: "`ellipse` has exactly the same effect as `circle`. The older syntax for this command is `ellipse ( x radius and y radius )`. As for the `circle` command, this syntax is not as good as the standard syntax."

Answer (score 21):

The notion is `xdim and ydim`, you are using `xdim, ydim`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\boundellipse}[3]% center, xdim, ydim
{(#1) ellipse (#2 and #3)
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw \boundellipse{0,0}{10}{5};
\draw \boundellipse{4,1}{-2}{4};
\draw \boundellipse{-2,4}{1}{3};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
    \usepackage{tikz}
        \begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=2]
     \draw (1,0) circle (2);
     \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: by far the simplest and best answer.

Comment: Why use scale if there's an `ellipse` function?

Comment: why not?................

Comment: @Leox Because this is a bad way of drawing an ellipse that would scale everything else in the drawing.

Comment: Throw it inside a scope and it will only scale the ellipse. Still wouldn't do it this way, but wouldn't be hard to resolve the issue hperkristiansen points out.