# Simple Tikz Hyperbola

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to recreate the hyperbola in the image. So far I have the beginning, by following the examples in [Drawing a hyperbola of a certain eccentricity in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108938/drawing-a-hyperbola-of-a-certain-eccentricity-in-tikz) and [How to draw an ellipse?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65018/how-to-draw-an-ellipse), in particular [cmhughes'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6621/cmhughes), suggestion in the comments of the previous question, but the top ellipse is lacking its upper half.

How can I fix this? Also can I do this using `\addplot3`?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\xm{5}
\def\ym{6.5}
\def\dom{2}

%\def\ecc{1.44022}
\def\ecc{2.3}
\def\a{1}
\def\b{(\a*sqrt((\ecc)^2-1)} 


\begin{axis}[scale=.8,
    hide axis,
    xmin=-\xm,xmax=\xm,
    ymin=-\ym,ymax=\ym]
    \addplot [domain=-\dom:\dom] ({\a*cosh(\x)},{\b*sinh(\x)});
    \addplot [domain=-\dom:\dom] ({-\a*cosh(\x)},{\b*sinh(\x)});

    \draw (0,0) ellipse (.55cm and .25cm);
    \draw (0,6) ellipse (1.3cm and .3cm);
%    \draw (0,-4) ellipse (1.8cm and .3cm);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Required[![][1]]
[image: Required[![][1]]

Comment: That is a hyperboloid, not a hyperbola.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an `\addplot3` example you can play with

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[hide axis,axis equal]
            \addplot3[surf,domain=0:360,y domain=-2:2]
                ({cosh(y)*cos(x)},{cosh(y)*sin(x)},{sinh(y)});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the excellent approaches suggested <s>but I was not satisfied with my 3D results (thus far)</s>. So I'd like to add what I came up with.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\definecolor{whitesmokedark}{RGB}{235,235,235}
\definecolor{gainsboro}{RGB}{220,220,220}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\xm{5}
\def\ym{10}
\def\df{3}
\def\dom{2}

%\def\ecc{1.44022}
\def\ecc{2.3}
\def\a{1}
\def\b{(\a*sqrt((\ecc)^2-1)} 

\begin{axis}[scale=.8,
    hide axis,
    xmin=-\xm,xmax=\xm,
    ymin=-\ym,ymax=\ym]

    \fill[gainsboro] (0,0) ellipse (.55cm and .2cm);
    \fill[whitesmokedark] (0,7.5) ellipse (2.1cm and .3cm);
    \fill[gainsboro] (0,-7.4) ellipse (2.05cm and .3cm);

    \addplot [domain=-\dom:\dom] ({\a*cosh(\x)},{\b*sinh(\x)});
    \addplot [domain=-\dom:\dom] ({-\a*cosh(\x)},{\b*sinh(\x)});

\end{axis}

\def\xax{2.7}
\draw[dotted] (\xax,\xax - 0.4) -- (\xax,\xax + 1);
\draw[solid, ->] (\xax,\xax + 1) -- (\xax,\xax + 1.7);
\draw[solid, ->] (\xax,\xax - 0.4) -- (1.5,2);
\draw[solid, ->] (\xax,\xax - 0.4) -- (4.5,2);

\node (x) at ( \xax -0.1,\xax + 1.3) [label=right:$x$] {};
\node (y) at (1.6,1.9) [label=above:$y$] {};
\node (z) at (4.5,1.9) [label=above:$z$] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which gives the picture below. (Critiques are very welcome.)

Edit
The 3D solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\definecolor{mediumgreen}{RGB}{0,153,0}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \begin{axis}[
    shader=interp,
    opacity=0.7,
    fill opacity=0.7,
    axis lines = none,
    ticks=none,
    axis equal
    ]

    \draw[thick,->,black] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$z$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (-1,-6,1) node[anchor=north east]{$y$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4.3) node[anchor=east]{$x$};

    \addplot3[%
        shader=interp,
        opacity = 0.6,
        fill opacity=0.6,
        surf,
        colormap = {whiteblack}{color(0cm)  = (mediumgreen);color(1cm) =      (black)},
        variable = \u,
        variable y = \v,
        domain = 0:180,
        y domain = 0:360,
    ]
    ({cos(u)*sin(v)}, {sin(u)*sin(v)}, {.1*cos(v)});

    \addplot3[surf,domain=0:360,y domain=-1.5:1.5]
         ({cosh(y)*cos(x)},{cosh(y)*sin(x)},{sinh(y)});

    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Hyperbola]
[image: 3D Hyperbola]