# How can I draw an ellipse so that four vertices don't lie on x -axes and y -axes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I read at here [How to draw an ellipse?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65018/how-to-draw-an-ellipse). If the equation of ellipse is `x^2/25+y^2/144=1`, I tried

```
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\boundellipse}[3]% center, xdim, ydim
{(#1) ellipse (#2 and #3)
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw \boundellipse{0,0}{5}{12};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I can not use the above code to draw 
the ellipse with four vertices `\left (-\dfrac{52}{5},-\dfrac{39}{5}\right )`, `\left (\dfrac{52}{5},\dfrac{39}{5}\right )`, `\left (-\dfrac{36}{5},\dfrac{48}{5}\right )`, `\left (\dfrac{36}{5},-\dfrac{48}{5}\right )`. Semi-major-length of ellipse is 12 and semi-minor-length is 5.

How can I draw that ellipse.

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry, but I think that your problem is not a TikZ problem. You should probably learn some math : the big radius is `sqrt((52/5)**2+(39/5)**2) = 13` and the small one is `sqrt((36/5)**2+(48/5)**2) = 12` and the main axis is rotated at 45°. So you have to do `\fill[red,rotate=45] (0,0) ellipse (13 and 12);`.

Comment: please show minimal document where your drawing of vertices fail. from your description is not very clear what you like to achieve.

Comment: The nodes do not sit on your ellipse, you can check this with `\node at ({52/5},{39/5}){$\left(\dfrac{52}{5},\dfrac{39}{5}\right )$};`. Is this really where you want to place these nodes?

Comment: @Kpym Thank you for your Comment. But, the angle does not 45.

Comment: Yes, I have to learn some math too : `atan(39/52)*180/pi ~ 36.87°` ;)

Answer (score 1):

this is rather extended comment ...

- this site is dedicated to `tex` problems
- as i can conclude you like to solve problem how to draw ellipse through four (arbitrary) vertices. this is math problem and is *off-topic* here

illustration how i understood your question:

[image]

mwe for above image:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,% for scaling coordinates of vertices
E/.style args = {#1/#2}{ellipse, draw,
                 minimum width=#1cm, % major length
                 minimum height=#2cm,% minor length
                 inner sep=0pt},
   dot/.style = {circle, fill}
                    ]
\node[E=24/10, rotate=0] {};
\node (a) [dot,
    pin=225: {$\left(-\mfrac{52}{5},-\mfrac{39}{5}\right)$}] at (-52/5,-39/5) {};
\node (b) [dot,
    pin= 45: {$\left( \mfrac{52}{5}, \mfrac{39}{5}\right)$}] at ( 52/5, 39/5) {};
\node (c) [dot,
    pin=135: {$\left(-\mfrac{36}{5},-\mfrac{48}{5}\right)$}] at (-36/5, 48/5) {};
\node (d) [dot,
    pin=315: {$\left( \mfrac{36}{5},-\mfrac{48}{5}\right)$}] at ( 36/5,-48/5) {};
%
\draw[red, dashed] (a) -- (d) -- (b) -- (c) -- (a);
% elipse 1
\node[E=24/10] {};  % <major length>/<minor length>
% elpise 2
\node[E=24/10, rotate=-9, dashed] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

when you have correct determined coordinates of vertices and calculated ellipse rotation angle (if needed), than you ask, how to draw such ellipse. basic idea, how can be ellipse drawn, is shown in above mwe.

Comment: @Zaeko Perhalp, I have to use a rotation to rotate the ellipse `x^2/25+y^2/144=1`. Now I am finding the angle of rotation.

Comment: if this solve your problem, then fine (but i doubt in this, coordinates of vertices, which are in pair reflex symmetric should be corners of square). what is now a question?